# System of linear equations.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A be a matrix of order $3\times 3$ having entries from $Z_3$. If rank of $A$ is 1 how to find the number of solutions to the homogeneous system $Ax = 0$?
My attempt:- By rank  nullity theorem, $\dim(\ker(A)) = 2$. So trivial solution is not the only solution.
Can anyone please help me further?

Answer (score 1):

The kernel is two dimensional by rank-nullity as you said, so there kernel is a two dimensional $\Bbb Z_3$ vector space, and has order $3^2=9$.